# MI.surv function in R for interval censored data

Tags: r, package, survival-analysis

In R package `MIICD`, we have a function `MI.surv`. We use this function to reach to exact time for interval-censored data. Consider the example given in the manual for this package. How can I use the output of this function to get the exact times?

```
res<-MI.surv(k = 5 , m = 5 , data = ICCRD , conf.int = TRUE , alpha = 0.05 )
```

The link to the MIICD manual :https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MIICD/MIICD.pdf  (page 6)

Comment: "Consider the example given in the manual for this package", could you please provide a link to that?

Comment: Here you are:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MIICD/MIICD.pdf     page 6

Comment: Do you have any idea for my question? I am really confused with this output. @AlejandroMontilla